# How to use Strapi V4 policies in a custom route?

Tags: strapi

I have created a custom route and a controller, which I will use to perform a task within my Strapi app.

However, I’m having a big problem, I’ve been searching for answers for hours and so far I haven’t found anything that would help me effectively.

`export default { routes: [ { method: "GET", path: "/zerei", handler: "zerei.index", config: { policies: ["global::is-authenticated"], }, }, ], };`

The problem is that policies are being ignored while my routes require authentication to be accessed.

The only way to make routes work is to make them public.
I don’t know if this information is relevant, but if I make the route public, the policies are triggered.

I’m using TypeScript and Strapi version is 4.15.5

I've already tried several things to solve the problem, and as I described above, the only thing that allowed me to execute any policy was making the route public, I even tried to use it with the public route but I can't find any data within the policyContext object that I can use to help identify who the user is or whether they are actually logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the policy first, so in your case, you need to create a policy file ./src/policies/is-authenticated.js, in this file you will have access to the policy context.

Below is the code for is-authenticated.js:

```
module.exports = (policyContext, config, { strapi }) => {
  if (policyContext.state.user) { // if a session is open
    // go to next policy or reach the controller's action
    return true;
  }

  return false; // If you return nothing, Strapi considers you didn't want to block the request and will let it pass
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If this endpoint is set for authenticated user, then you need to have authentication token in client request. The policy is called after token is verified.